# Getting error when trying to calculate the length of the array after sort in python

Tags: python, sorting, variable-length

I am totally confused on the below code execution,

```
a= [10,30,4]
a = a.sort()
r = len(a) - 1
print (r)
```

When the above code is executed I get
**r = len(a) - 1
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()**

However the code runs fine if I find the length without sorting or when sorting the array after find the length. Is there any reason to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.sort()` is an inplace operation. It modify list inplace and does not return anything. See the documentation for `list.sort` by typing `help(list.sort)` in your python interpreter.

```
>>> help([].sort)
Help on built-in function sort:

sort(*, key=None, reverse=False) method of builtins.list instance
    Sort the list in ascending order and return None.

    The sort is in-place (i.e. the list itself is modified) and stable (i.e. the
    order of two equal elements is maintained).
```

So the point is, you should not assign the return value of `listobject.sort()` because it will always return `None`

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by a function `sort` is `None`

So when you are trying to assign `a = a.sort()` it is the same as `a = None`

Here is the reference to [sorting basics](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics)

Your code should look like

```
a= [10,30,4]
a.sort()
r = len(a) - 1
print (r)
```

Comment: Hi! Would you consider improving your answer by explaining the differences between `list.sort` and `sorted`, and including a link to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if you want a non-inplace function then you can run:

`a = sorted(a)`